# Replaced Piece of roof sheathing, forgot to use 1/8th inch space - should I be worried?

Tags: roof

I replaced a piece of plywood about 4x8ft on my roof, I did not take into account the recommended 1/8th inch gap suggested to be used between decking.

Should I be worried? I haven't attached singles yet but I have nailed it down and I would rather not remove it if possible.

Comment: It is a lot easier to remove it now than later.

Answer (score 3):

The gap is to allow for expansion due to heat and humidity. If you just installed it this summer I wouldn't lose any sleep over it. It is already pretty warm and humid so the wood should be near its maximum dimensions. One sheet out of many is not likely to cause any problems.

If you are really OCD then take a circular saw and set the depth shallow at the thickness of the plywood so you don't cut into the trusses. Then cut along the butt joint with the other sheets. This will create a gap the width of the blade ~1/16".

Good luck!

Comment: Moisture content changes (due to humidity changes) affect wood's dimensions far more than temperature changes do.